# Parsing python grammar with boost::spirit - problem

Tags: c++, python, parsing, boost-spirit

I am trying to write a python parser with boost::spirit library. Here is the code:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class Parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, space_type>
{
public:
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(small_stmt)
    {
        NEWLINE = lit("<NEWLINE>");
        INDENT = lit("<INDENT>");
        DEDENT = lit("<DEDENT>");
        ENDMARKER = lit("<EOT>");
        NAME = identifier.alias();
        NUMBER = integer|longinteger|floatnumber|imagnumber;
        STRING = stringliteral.alias();

        identifier = (alpha | '_') >> *(alpha | digit | '_');

        stringliteral = -stringprefix  >> (shortstring | longstring);
        stringprefix = lit("r") | lit("u") | lit("ur") | lit("R") | lit("U") | lit("UR") | lit("Ur") | lit("uR") | lit("b") | lit("B") | lit("br") | lit("Br") | lit("bR") | lit("BR");
        shortstring =  "'" >> *(shortstringitem - "'") >> "'" | "\"" >> *(shortstringitem - "\"") >> "\"";
        longstring = "'''" >> *longstringitem >> "'''" | "\"\"\"" >> *longstringitem >> "\"\"\"";
        shortstringitem = shortstringchar | escapeseq;
        longstringitem = longstringchar | escapeseq;
        shortstringchar = char_ - "\\" - "\n";
        longstringchar = char_ - "\\";
        escapeseq = '\\' >> char_;

        longinteger = integer >> (lit("l") | lit("L"));
        integer = decimalinteger | octinteger | hexinteger | bininteger;
        decimalinteger = nonzerodigit >> *digit | lit("0");
        octinteger = lit("0") >> (lit("o") | lit("O")) >> +octdigit | lit("0") >> +octdigit;
        hexinteger = lit("0") >> (lit("x") | lit("X")) >> +hexdigit;
        bininteger = lit("0") >> (lit("b") | lit("B")) >> +bindigit;
        nonzerodigit = char_('1', '9');
        octdigit = char_('0', '7');
        bindigit = lit("0") | lit("1");
        hexdigit = digit | char_('a', 'f') | char_('A', 'F');

        floatnumber = pointfloat | exponentfloat;
        pointfloat = -intpart >> fraction | intpart >> ".";
        exponentfloat = (intpart | pointfloat) >> exponent;
        intpart = +digit;
        fraction = "." >> +digit;
        exponent = (lit("e") | lit("E")) >> -(lit("+") | lit("-")) >> +digit;

        imagnumber = (floatnumber | intpart) >> (lit("j") | lit("J"));

        single_input = NEWLINE|simple_stmt|compound_stmt >> NEWLINE;
        file_input = *(NEWLINE|stmt) >> ENDMARKER;
        eval_input = testlist >> *NEWLINE >> ENDMARKER;
        decorator = lit("@") >> dotted_name >> -( lit("(") >> -(arglist) >> lit(")") ) >> NEWLINE;
        decorators = +decorator;
        decorated = decorators >> (classdef|funcdef);
        funcdef = lit("def") >> NAME >> parameters >> lit(":") >> suite;
        parameters = lit("(") >> -(varargslist) >> lit(")");
        varargslist = (*(fpdef >> -(lit("=") >> test) >> lit(",")) >> (lit("*") >> NAME >> -(lit(",") >> lit("**") >> NAME)|lit("**") >> NAME)|fpdef >> -(lit("=") >> test) >> *(lit(",") >> fpdef >> -(lit("=") >> test)) >> -(lit(",")));
        fpdef = NAME|lit("(") >> fplist >> lit(")");
        fplist = fpdef >> *(lit(",") >> fpdef) >> -(lit(","));
        stmt = simple_stmt|compound_stmt;
        simple_stmt = small_stmt >> *(lit(";") >> small_stmt) >> -(lit(";")) >> NEWLINE;
        small_stmt = (expr_stmt|print_stmt|del_stmt|pass_stmt|flow_stmt|import_stmt|global_stmt|exec_stmt|assert_stmt);
        expr_stmt = testlist >> (augassign >> (yield_expr|testlist)|*(lit("=") >> (yield_expr|testlist)));
        augassign = (lit("+=")|lit("-=")|lit("*=")|lit("/=")|lit("%=")|lit("&=")|lit("|=")|lit("^=")|lit("<<=")|lit(">>=")|lit("**=")|lit("//="));
        print_stmt = lit("print") >> ( -( test >> *(lit(",") >> test) >> -(lit(",")) )|lit(">>") >> test >> -( +(lit(",") >> test) >> -(lit(",")) ) );
        del_stmt = lit("del") >> exprlist;
        pass_stmt = lit("pass");
        flow_stmt = break_stmt|continue_stmt|return_stmt|raise_stmt|yield_stmt;
        break_stmt = lit("break");
        continue_stmt = lit("continue");
        return_stmt = lit("return") >> -(testlist);
        yield_stmt = yield_expr.alias();
        raise_stmt = lit("raise") >> -(test >> -(lit(",") >> test >> -(lit(",") >> test)));
        import_stmt = import_name|import_from;
        import_name = lit("import") >> dotted_as_names;
        import_from = (lit("from") >> (*lit(".") >> dotted_name|+lit(".")) >> lit("import") >> (lit("*")|lit("(") >> import_as_names >> lit(")")|import_as_names));
        import_as_name = NAME >> -(lit("as") >> NAME);
        dotted_as_name = dotted_name >> -(lit("as") >> NAME);
        import_as_names = import_as_name >> *(lit(",") >> import_as_name) >> -(lit(","));
        dotted_as_names = dotted_as_name >> *(lit(",") >> dotted_as_name);
        dotted_name = NAME >> *(lit(".") >> NAME);
        global_stmt = lit("global") >> NAME >> *(lit(",") >> NAME);
        exec_stmt = lit("exec") >> expr >> -(lit("in") >> test >> -(lit(",") >> test));
        assert_stmt = lit("assert") >> test >> -(lit(",") >> test);
        compound_stmt = if_stmt|while_stmt|for_stmt|try_stmt|with_stmt|funcdef|classdef|decorated;
        if_stmt = lit("if") >> test >> lit(":") >> suite >> *(lit("elif") >> test >> lit(":") >> suite) >> -(lit("else") >> lit(":") >> suite);
        while_stmt = lit("while") >> test >> lit(":") >> suite >> -(lit("else") >> lit(":") >> suite);
        for_stmt = lit("for") >> exprlist >> lit("in") >> testlist >> lit(":") >> suite >> -(lit("else") >> lit(":") >> suite);
        try_stmt = (lit("try") >> lit(":") >> suite >> (+(except_clause >> lit(":") >> suite) >> -(lit("else") >> lit(":") >> suite) >> -(lit("finally") >> lit(":") >> suite)|lit("finally") >> lit(":") >> suite));
        with_stmt = lit("with") >> with_item >> *(lit(",") >> with_item) >> lit(":") >> suite;
        with_item = test >> -(lit("as") >> expr);
        except_clause = lit("except") >> -(test >> -((lit("as")|lit(",")) >> test));
        suite = simple_stmt|NEWLINE >> INDENT >> +stmt >> DEDENT;
        testlist_safe = old_test >> -(+(lit(",") >> old_test) >> -(lit(",")));
        old_test = or_test|old_lambdef;
        old_lambdef = lit("lambda") >> -(varargslist) >> lit(":") >> old_test;
        test = or_test >> -(lit("if") >> or_test >> lit("else") >> test)|lambdef;
        or_test = and_test >> *(lit("or") >> and_test);
        and_test = not_test >> *(lit("and") >> not_test);
        not_test = lit("not") >> not_test|comparison;
        comparison = expr >> *(comp_op >> expr);
        comp_op = lit("<")|lit(">")|lit("==")|lit(">=")|lit("<=")|lit("<>")|lit("!=")|lit("in")|lit("not in")|lit("is")|lit("is not");
        expr = xor_expr >> *(lit("|") >> xor_expr);
        xor_expr = and_expr >> *(lit("^") >> and_expr);
        and_expr = shift_expr >> *(lit("&") >> shift_expr);
        shift_expr = arith_expr >> *((lit("<<")|lit(">>")) >> arith_expr);
        arith_expr = term >> *((lit("+")|lit("-")) >> term);
        term = factor >> *((lit("*")|lit("/")|lit("%")|lit("//")) >> factor);
        factor = (lit("+")|lit("-")|lit("~")) >> factor|power;
        power = atom >> *trailer >> -(lit("**") >> factor);
        atom = (lit("(") >> -(yield_expr|testlist_comp) >> lit(")")|lit("-(") >> -(listmaker) >> lit(")")|lit("{") >> -(dictorsetmaker) >> lit("}")|lit("`") >> testlist1 >> lit("`")|NAME|NUMBER|+STRING);
        listmaker = test >> ( list_for|*(lit(",") >> test) >> -(lit(",")) );
        testlist_comp = test >> ( comp_for|*(lit(",") >> test) >> -(lit(",")) );
        lambdef = lit("lambda") >> -(varargslist) >> lit(":") >> test;
        trailer = lit("(") >> -(arglist) >> lit(")")|lit("[") >> subscriptlist >> lit("]")|lit(".") >> NAME;
        subscriptlist = subscript >> *(lit(",") >> subscript) >> -(lit(","));
        subscript = lit(".") >> lit(".") >> lit(".")|test|-(test) >> lit(":") >> -(test) >> -(sliceop);
        sliceop = lit(":") >> -(test);
        exprlist = expr >> *(lit(",") >> expr) >> -(lit(","));
        testlist = test >> *(lit(",") >> test) >> -(lit(","));
        dictorsetmaker = ( (test >> lit(":") >> test >> (comp_for|*(lit(",") >> test >> lit(":") >> test) >> -(lit(","))))|(test >> (comp_for|*(lit(",") >> test) >> -(lit(",")))) );
        classdef = lit("class") >> NAME >> -(lit("(") >> -(testlist) >> lit(")")) >> lit(":") >> suite;
        arglist = *(argument >> lit(",")) >> (argument >> -(lit(","))|lit("*") >> test >> *(lit(",") >> argument) >> -(lit(",") >> lit("**") >> test)|lit("**") >> test);
        argument = test >> -(comp_for)|test >> lit("=") >> test;
        list_iter = list_for|list_if;
        list_for = lit("for") >> exprlist >> lit("in") >> testlist_safe >> -(list_iter);
        list_if = lit("if") >> old_test >> -(list_iter);
        comp_iter = comp_for|comp_if;
        comp_for = lit("for") >> exprlist >> lit("in") >> or_test >> -(comp_iter);
        comp_if = lit("if") >> old_test >> -(comp_iter);
        testlist1 = test >> *(lit(",") >> test);
        encoding_decl = NAME.alias();
        yield_expr = lit("yield") >> -(testlist);


    }

    // LEXEMS
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> NEWLINE;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> INDENT;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> DEDENT;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> ENDMARKER;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> NAME;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> NUMBER;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> STRING;

    // IDENTIFIER
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> identifier;

    // STRING LITERAL
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> stringliteral;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> stringprefix;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> shortstring;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> longstring;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> shortstringitem;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> longstringitem;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> shortstringchar;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> longstringchar;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> escapeseq;

    // INTEGER LITERAL
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> longinteger;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> integer;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> decimalinteger;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> octinteger;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> hexinteger;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> bininteger;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> nonzerodigit;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> octdigit;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> bindigit;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> hexdigit;

    // FLOAT LITERAL
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> floatnumber;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> pointfloat;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> exponentfloat;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> intpart;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> fraction;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> exponent;

    //IMAGINARY LITERAL
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> imagnumber;

    // PYTHON GRAMMAR
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> single_input;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> file_input;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> eval_input;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> decorator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> decorators;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> decorated;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> funcdef;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> parameters;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> varargslist;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> fpdef;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> fplist;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> simple_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> small_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> expr_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> augassign;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> print_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> del_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> pass_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> flow_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> break_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> continue_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> return_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> yield_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> raise_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> import_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> import_name;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> import_from;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> import_as_name;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> dotted_as_name;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> import_as_names;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> dotted_as_names;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> dotted_name;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> global_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> exec_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> assert_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> compound_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> if_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> while_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> for_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> try_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> with_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> with_item;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> except_clause;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> suite;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> testlist_safe;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> old_test;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> old_lambdef;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> test;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> or_test;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> and_test;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> not_test;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> comparison;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> comp_op;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> xor_expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> and_expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> shift_expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> arith_expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> term;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> factor;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> power;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> atom;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> listmaker;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> testlist_comp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> lambdef;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> trailer;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> subscriptlist;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> subscript;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> sliceop;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> exprlist;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> testlist;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> dictorsetmaker;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> classdef;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> arglist;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> argument;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> list_iter;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> list_for;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> list_if;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> comp_iter;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> comp_for;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> comp_if;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> testlist1;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> encoding_decl;
    qi::rule<Iterator, space_type> yield_expr;
};
```

The problem is that when I try to parse simple file:

```
pass
```

witch after going through some lexer module is:

```
pass <NEWLINE> <EOT>
```

the parsing failed and stops at first character.
When I tried to parse this file with **pass_stmt** rule everything is ok (except that we still have  and  remaining, but pass word was "consumed").
When I tried to parse it with rule one level up - **small_stmt** - parser stops at

```
> <EOT>
```

consuming

```
pass <NEWLINE
```

One level up - **simple_stmt** gives same result as **file_input** - parser stops at first character.

Before adding grammar defined in PYTHON GRAMMAR section (get from http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html) everything was working properly. Parser recognized identifiers, literals, numbers etc.

Does anybody have an idea what can be wrong here?

Comment: This is a guess -- it looks to me like small_stmt shouldn't consume the newline, because simple_stmt expects that the newline should still be present.

Comment: another possible problem: small_stmt tries to match expr_stmt first -- but "pass" might be considered a valid expression (I dunno I haven't looked that far) if it parses as an identifier.

Comment: If your compiler supports C++0x, you may try AXE parser generator. I've never had difficulties debugging parsers with it. Adding debugging semantic actions to the rules of the fly with lambdas makes debugging pretty effortless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you enable debugging as explained [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/debugging/). This will give you insights what's actually happening. Generally, I suggest building grammars step by step and not trying to implement everything in one big leap.

The code you provided above is very difficult to understand for un-unitiated readers as it is very large and not commented. Writing grammars is very much like writing 'normal' code. Encapsulation is the key to success. Try building smaller grammars covering self-contained pieces and combine those sub-grammars as required. See [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/best-practices/) for some best practices.

Comment: Debugging method that you've mentioned is really helpful. It shows me where the problem is. It seems that the parser recognize pass word as an identifier not as a pass_stmt. It enters the path connected with identifier and doesn't try any other matches. Is there any way to tell parser which rule is more important (should be tried first)?

Comment: Generally, alternatives are tried in the sequence they are defined in. Therefore, if you move your keyword rule first it should be tried before your identifier rule.

Comment: Thank you for your help - debugging tool is great. As it turned out, the official Python grammar was given in an unfavorable order which caused that parser often wandered around.